# vim and unix pipe

Tags: shell, unix, vim

By mistake I ran a funny command today that looks like
**vi filename | vi -** .
It made my terminal stuck even Ctrl-C was of no use.
I had to close the terminal only. 
I tried it a couple of times and tried on my friend machine too. Just wondering why Ctrl-C was also not able to help.

Answer (score 3):

**vi** is reading from stdin.

When you edit in **vi**  **Ctrl+c** does not work either.

To quit **vi** use **:q** or **:q!** will work like in a normal **vi** session.

Comment: Thank you! I sometimes manage to call `vim file | foo` and this seems to also hang the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Using the POSIX function signal() a C program can choose what to do if there is a keyboard interrupt.

Here is an example (copied from [this site](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/signal_handling.html)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

FILE *temp_file;
void leave(int sig);

main() {
    (void) signal(SIGINT, leave);
    temp_file = fopen("tmp", "w");

    for(;;) {
        /*
        * Do things....
        */
        printf("Ready...\n");
        (void)getchar();
    }

    /* cant get here ... */
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

/*
 * on receipt of SIGINT, close tmp file
 */
void leave(int sig) {
    fprintf(temp_file,"\nInterrupted..\n");
    fclose(temp_file);
    exit(sig);
}
```

But as you can see, vi doesn't use the keyboard interrupt to exit. It doesn't matter whether you are using it in a pipe or not.

Answer (score 0):

Vi intercepts `ctrl-c` (it is almost equivalent to `esc`) so `ctrl-c` would not work to quit the application in that setting.

I could escape from that trap by using `ctrl-z` and then using `kill %`